# Delete an added line and save it to XML

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, datagridview

I have created an Windows Form Application in C#. With this application I load an XML file into the Datagridview. This application is be able to edit, delete and add lines in to the XML file.

I have created a second form where I can add key and value into my XML file:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xDoc.Load(@"c:\users\khaab\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ReadingXML\test.xml");
    XmlNode xNode = xDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "add", "");
    XmlAttribute xKey = xDoc.CreateAttribute("key");
    XmlAttribute xValue = xDoc.CreateAttribute("value");
    xKey.Value = KeyTextBox.Text;
    xValue.Value = ValueTextBox.Text;
    xNode.Attributes.Append(xKey);
    xNode.Attributes.Append(xValue);
    xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("appSettings")[0].InsertAfter(xNode,
    xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("appSettings")[0].LastChild);    
    xDoc.Save(@"c:\users\khaab\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ReadingXML\test.xml");

    this.Close();
}
```

After I am adding this two lines it will get into my datagridview, but after I want to delete it and try to save it, the line doesn't remove from XML file.

Save function:

```
private void SaveChanges()
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(@"c:\users\khaab\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ReadingXML\test.xml");
    XmlNodeList nodes = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/configuration/appSettings/add");
    //doc.RemoveAll();
    foreach (var item in _settings)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Count; i++)
        {
            if (nodes[i].Attributes[0].Value.Equals(item.Key))
            {
                nodes[i].Attributes[1].Value = item.Value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Delete function:

```
    private void deleteRowToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    int rowIndex = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
    dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
    _settings.RemoveAt(rowIndex);


    //dataGridView1.DataSource = _settings;
    BindDataGrid();
}
```

XML File:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <configuration>
 <appSettings>

 <add key="" value="" />
 <add key="" value="" />
 <add key="" value="" />
 <add key="" value="" />
 <add key="" value="" />
 <add key="" value="" />
 <add key="" value="" />
 <add key="" value="" />

</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

What I am doing wrong and whats the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the '*SaveChanges*' method you only update existing keys, therefore the existing keys will remain and new keys won't be added. During saving you need to completely rewrite the XML file with data from the table. Also you need save '*XmlDocument*' after changing using '*doc.Save(...)*'.

**UPD:**
Change 'SaveChanges' method to this:

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load(@"c:\users\khaab\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ReadingXML\test.xml");
var list = xDoc.DocumentElement["appSettings"];
list.RemoveAll();
foreach (var item in _settings)
{
  XmlNode xNode = xDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "add", "");
  XmlAttribute xKey = xDoc.CreateAttribute("key");
  XmlAttribute xValue = xDoc.CreateAttribute("value");
  xKey.Value = item.Key;
  xValue.Value = item.Value;
  xNode.Attributes.Append(xKey);
  xNode.Attributes.Append(xValue);
  xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("appSettings")[0].InsertAfter(xNode, xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("appSettings")[0].LastChild);
}
xDoc.Save(@"c:\users\khaab\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ReadingXML\test.xml");
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't have an idea how I can do that, can you help me with that with an example please or solution? The reason is that I am beginner in C#.

Comment: Tnx. I add correct code example for 'SaveChanges' method into my reply.

Comment: For an easier working with Xml files can try [XmlSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx).